# Protractor - How to resolve the promise to get number output

Tags: protractor

I have the following method in my helper class. I need the method to return the rowNum of Number type. But I always get a Promise when i call the method. I want to see the number when I call the method.

```
getRowNum(table, colNum, searchText) {
        let rowNum = -1;

        return table.all(by.css("tbody tr td:nth-child(" + colNum + ")")).map(function (element) {
            return element.getText();
        }).then(function (textArray) {
            for (var i in textArray) {
                if (textArray[i].trim().indexOf(searchText) != -1) {
                    console.log(i);
                    console.log(textArray[i]);
                    rowNum = i + 1;
                }
            }
            return rowNum;
        });
});

//I'm using it in my other js file like this
let rowNum = helper.getRowNum($("div.sponsor-table table"), 2, "some text");
```

Comment: Because you made function `getRowNum()` return a promise. So `let rowNum=` is promise too.  you need to get promise eventual value in 'then()', like `rowNum.then(function(val){ console.log('row num:', val) })`

Comment: Oops my bad. I didn't realize it. May be my years long Java experience.

Comment: @yong, your code actually prints the proper value but if I assign the value to a variable, in my case rowNum, it gets a Promise instead of number. How to properly assign the value to a variable?

Comment: you can consider to use `async/await`  http://www.protractortest.org/#/async-await

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
    getRowNum = (table, colNum, searchText) => {
        let rowNum = -1;
        let text;
        table.all(by.css("tbody tr td:nth-child(" + colNum + ")")).map(function (element) {
            return text = element.getText();
        })
        .then(function () {
            for (var i in text) {
                if (text[i].trim().indexOf(searchText) != -1) {
                    console.log(i);
                    console.log(text[i]);
                    rowNum = i + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return rowNum;
        });
    };
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks for your answer; though I was able to get the intended output, my problem was, after the returned output of the method is assigned to a variable, variable has promise instead of a actual value. I needed a way to resolve the promise and get the value.